# Дислокацию можно "поменять", сочетабельно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Мы поменяли дислокацию.

(Пересели из-под солнышка в тенёчек.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Дислокация** это — термин (*изменить дислокацию дивизии*), в словарях указано только терминологическое значение.

В данном тексте **авторское расширение значение слова** (с оттенком иронии). В принципе такое расширенное употребление слова встречается, например:

Это не позволит игроку **изменить дислокацию** во время игры. [С. Ф. Сопрунов, А. А. Ганичев. // «Информационные технологии», 2003.06.23]

Планы есть какие-нибудь долгоиграющие? Уехать в столицу, **поменять дислокацию…** [Дмитрий Здомский. Индустриальные киборги из Yo-бурга (2004) ]

ДИСЛОКАЦИЯ

1. ж. Размещение войсковых частей и военных учреждений на какой-л. территории, распределение авиационных войск по аэродромам, кораблей по портам.
2. ж.Смещение пластов земной коры (в геологии). Толковый словарь Ефремовой. 2012